# While loop and Python with NAO

Tags: python, while-loop, nao-robot

So i've got a Code with Python and i'm trying to make it work with NAO (Aldebaran Robotics)

```
import time
class MyClass(GeneratedClass):
    def __init__(self):
        GeneratedClass.__init__(self)
        self.motion = ALProxy("ALMotion")
        self.maxTour = 3
        self.reponse = False

    def onLoad(self):
        #~ puts code for box initialization here
        self.tournerDroite()
        time.sleep(5)
        #detect ball
        self.tournerCentre()
        time.sleep(5)
         #detect ball
        self.turnLeft()
         #detect ball
        #self.notInCenter()
        #self.redBall()
        pass

    def onUnload(self):
        #~ puts code for box cleanup here
        pass

    def onInput_onStart(self, ):
        #~ self.onStopped() #~ activate output of the box
        pass

    def onInput_onStop(self):
        self.onUnload() #~ it is recommanded to call onUnload of this box in a onStop method, as the code written in onUnload is used to stop the box as well
        pass

    def turnRight(self):
        self.motion.setStiffnesses("HeadYaw", 0)
        self.motion.setAngles("HeadYaw", -0.5, 0.05)
        self.motion.setStiffnesses("HeadYaw", 1)
        pass
    def turnLeft(self):
        self.motion.setStiffnesses("HeadYaw", 0)
        self.motion.setAngles("HeadYaw", 0.5, 0.05)
        self.motion.setStiffnesses("HeadYaw", 1)
        pass
    def turnCenter(self):
        self.motion.setStiffnesses("HeadYaw", 0)
        self.motion.setAngles("HeadYaw", 0, 0.05)
        self.motion.setStiffnesses("HeadYaw", 1)
        pass

    def notInCenter(self):
        if(self.motion.getAngles("HeadYaw", True) != 0):
            self.turnCenter()
            return True
        else:
            return False
        pass

    def redBall(self):
        while self.reponse == False:
            self.turnRight()
            time.sleep(5)
            #detect ball

            self.turnCenter()
            time.sleep(5)
             #detect ball
            self.turnLeft()
             #detect ball
        pass
```

The problem is that in `onLoad()`, the robot turn is head Right, then Center, then Left but when i use the `redBall()`, it doesn't, it just turn right and center, and go back and forth.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `time.sleep(5)` after `self.turnLeft()` in `redBall`? Because now, when you call turnLeft, the loop immediately continues and it calls turnRight again. That means it won't have time to do the turn to the left.

Comment: haha, this is really silly, but it's true and now it's working, can you put it in a proper answer so i can validate it.

Comment: No problem, I've added an answer with pretty much the same content.

Comment: Also, you don't need to end a function in Python with `pass`. You only need it in functions which are not written yet (such as `onUnload`) and other places where Python expects at least one line of code. When there's already some code, it's no longer needed to write `pass`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be `time.sleep(5)` after `self.turnLeft()` in `redBall`.

When you call turnLeft, the loop immediately continues and it calls turnRight again. That means it won't have time to do the turn to the left. That's why it does a right and center turn but no left turn.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're using setStiffnesses in an inverted way: 0 remove the power from the motor, and 1 set the power.

So:
        self.motion.setStiffnesses("HeadYaw", 0)
        self.motion.setAngles("HeadYaw", -0.5, 0.05)
        self.motion.setStiffnesses("HeadYaw", 1)

is removing the power, then turn head, but do nothing because there's no power, then set the power => nothing